# Ogr2ogr: ERROR 1: PROJ: pj_obj_create: Cannot find proj.db

Tags: gdal, mapinfo, windows-10, conda

I start using GDAL 3.0.0 using conda build. I successfully installed GDAL on my laptop (Windows 10) and I am trying to ingest MapInfo tab file into Elasticsearch index. I understood that I have to create mapping first before ingesting it into Elasticsearch.

```
ogr2ogr -progress -lco MAPPING="D:\mymappings\map.text" -f "ElasticSearch" http://localhost:9700 "D:\MIProTab.tab"
```

But when I try to execute the above command then it is giving me the following error:

```
C:\Users\ABCD>ogr2ogr -progress -lco MAPPING="D:\mymappings\map.text" -f "ElasticSearch" http://localhost:9700 "D:\MIProTab.tab"
ERROR 1: PROJ: pj_obj_create: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: createGeodeticReferenceFrame: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: createGeodeticReferenceFrame: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_as_wkt: Cannot find proj.db
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

C:\Users\ABCD>
```

I checked other's solution where it is mentioned to have gdal.dll to be present on the same directory where ogr2ogr is present. Also, I have set the environment variable "PROJ_LIB" but all went in vain. 
What is wrong here?

Comment: GDAL needs to find the file "proj.db" that contains all the definitions for the coordinate systems. I do not know where conda is placing in the zip file from gisinternals.com it seems to be in …\bin\proj6\share.

Comment: this location is not present there. I also downloaded the GDAL core from gisinternals.com and try to run the same above command. But it doesn't work out.

Comment: Do you get the same error about missing proj.db?

Comment: How did you install GDAL the first time?

Comment: I installed anaconda/minconda python and then i use "conda" installer.

Answer (score 13):

I set the PROJ_LIB environment variable to point to the PROJ.4 data directory (where proj.db lives) and this problem has been solved,hope that is useful to you.

Comment: Sorry. but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. Of course you have to restart the software (including shells such as cmd boxes) to load this new environment setting into the ogr2ogr environment.

Comment: While importing pyproj in the python virtual environment the error I got was ```EPSG code is unknown. PROJ: proj_create_from_database: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\contrib\postgis-3.0\proj\proj.db lacks DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MAJOR / DATABASE.LAYOUT.VERSION.MINOR metadata. It comes from another PROJ installation.``` The conflict was because the pyproj was also installed in PostgreSQL, I Changed environment variable to directory where pyproj was installed in the virtual environent to ```C:\python_envs\geocube\Lib\site-packages\pyproj\proj_dir\share\proj``` and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Check your environment_variable:

```
setx GDAL_DATA "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal-data"
setx GDAL_DRIVER_PATH "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins"
setx PROJ_LIB "C:\Program Files\GDAL\projlib"
setx PYTHONPATH "C:\Program Files\GDAL\"
```

Comment: suggest using 'set', instead of the permanent 'setx'

Comment: Thanks this helped. For @TheoF in windows 10 you need to use setx if you want it to be a permanent change: https://superuser.com/questions/916649/what-is-the-difference-between-setx-and-set-in-environment-variables-in-windows

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto yes, like I said. I suggest not using setx for testing.

Answer (score 5):

**Add these commands to your code at the beginning**. **Your issue will be solved**.

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:\\Users\\Sai kiran\\anaconda3\\envs\\sai\\Library\\share\\proj'
os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = 'C:\\Users\\Sai kiran\\anaconda3\\envs\sai\\Library\\share'
```

Search for the location of your `proj.db` file in your anaconda directory and replace the same location with `C:\\Users\\Sai kiran\\anaconda3\\envs\\sai\\Library\\share\\proj`in the above command. Also, specify the location of `gdal` folder in the anaconda directory as in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

To use GDAL and/or PROJ from conda, you need to [activate](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/glossary.html#activate-deactivate-environment) the environment, which sets the necessary environment variables (including `GDAL_DATA` and `PROJ_LIB`).

If you have `conda` on your path, it's simply `conda activate base` (or other environment).

---

If you don't have `conda` on your path, you can activate this a bit differently. For example, to activate the "base" Anaconda3 environment for Windows:

```
call %LOCALAPPDATA%\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat base
```

Or for Linux:

```
. $HOME/anaconda3/bin/activate base
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straightforward once you know how to prepare the command environment - that was the bit I couldn't figure out. You can do as above or if you have already installed QGIS then this should work:

**ogr2ogr** is the tool but in order to use it some parameters qgis takes care of must be known (like where the projection information is) by the stand alone utility:

1. If ogr2ogr was installed with QGIS (like mine was) then start a cmd
   session in `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4\bin`
2. Run `o4w_env.bat` - this sets
   all the environment variables required to use ogr at the cmd
3. Execute your export command.  In my case it was

   ```
   ogr2ogr.exe -f SQLite -dsco SPATIALITE=yes "C:\temp\osm_lines" PG:"dbname=thedbasename user=theuser password=thepwd" public.planet_osm_line
   ```

This link was helpful for the ogr2ogr cmd syntax.

https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/SpatiaLite

Answer (score -1):

I tried following method and succeed:

```
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'E:\Programs\anaconda3\envs\gis\Library\share\proj'
```